# Debug sales order workflow in OpenERP 6.1 web client

Tags: odoo

I'm testing out the OpenERP 6.1 web client, and I sometimes have a sales order or other kind of document that gets stuck for some reason. I want to be able to look at the workflow diagram  for this document to see exactly where it is stuck.

One example that happened to me was a sales order that had shipped and the invoice was paid, but the sales order still wasn't done. After some digging, I found that one of the procurements was still running.

I can still print the workflow from the GTK client, but isn't there some way to print it from the web client?

I found a couple of ways to get at the screen that lets me edit the workflow, but that's not what I'm looking for. I want to print the diagram that shows the current state of the workflow instance for the open document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes I agree with the Ruchir comment that in web-client you can not print workflow, but I would like to remind that from some of the views we have [`Process View`](http://doc.openerp.com/v6.0/book/7/7_18_Process/index.html#ch-process) Implemented which are interactive and Useful to show  your business process.

To see how you can use it follow the following link [Managing your Sales Quotations](http://doc.openerp.com/v6.0/book/6/6_16_Sales/6_16_Sales_quotations.html#sales-quotations) This will guide at the end how you can use the Process view.
Like When you Draft your Quotation your Some process Ndoe will be in Red End Color other will be Gray then if you move forward the state will keep on changing, and advantage over here is they are interactive you can jump to specific node related view so you can drive you Sale process very fast and interactively.

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

from webclient it is not possible to print workflow . so for that you have to use GTK client.