# Why does the workflow calls the function twice & how to overide it?

Tags: odoo

I have created a workflow and its working perfectly.
The function called by the workflow activity is this

```
  def employee_confirm(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):  
    print "Entering >>>employee_confirm"
    return self.write(cr, uid, ids, {'state':'confirm'})
```

My problem is that the print statement is execute twice.
which means the function is being executed twice.

It's OK for this

```
self.write(cr, uid, ids, {'state':'confirm'})
```

Because it's a `write`.

For any other statement we cannot allow it twice for the same record.

Why this is happening & how to override this ?

Comment: I got the problem but i can say clear without seeing your code where you are triggering the workflow trigger cause their can be possibility that workflow service and button or some other piece of code is triggering same function so why you getting twice print, or their can be possibility workflow is customized wrong.

Comment: either you can use the python pdb module and debug all or you can out print statements at suspicious place and see who is responsible for double trigger.

Comment: Thanks. I found out the problem is in workflow activity.It had the line '<field name="split_mode">OR</field>' from some old code.

Comment: Ah alright, Great,  workflow are quite a sensitive and also imp and takes time to trace all point, Good work

Answer (score 0):

Understanding and debugging the workflow code is one of the hardest tasks when building a new OpenERP module. I found that [tracing the code in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9086069/4794) was the only way to see what was going on, but it took a long time.

Here's a SQL query I wrote to summarize the workflow transitions. I printed out the workflow diagrams and then copied this data onto the diagrams. As far as I know, you can only print the diagrams from the GTK client, [not the web client](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11270536/4794). Open the screen with the workflow you want, then from the Plugins menu choose Execute a Plugin and double click Print Workflow.

```
    select  wkf.name, 
            f.name || '(' || f.id || ')' as src, 
            f.kind,
            f.action as from_action,
            f.split_mode, 
            f.flow_start,
            t.name || '(' || t.id || ')' as dest, 
            t.kind as dest_kind,
            t.action as dest_action,
            t.join_mode, 
            t.flow_stop, 
            tr.*
    from wkf_transition tr
    join wkf_activity f
    on tr.act_from = f.id
    join wkf_activity t
    on tr.act_to = t.id
    join wkf
    on f.wkf_id = wkf.id
    order by wkf.name, f.name, t.name
```